# Retrieve the status of a contract by its creator

Tags: contract-development, contract-invocation

In a situation where there are multiple contracts stored in different blocks, is there any method to retrieve the status of a contract through its owner's address? (*e.g.* *in my situation, each person registered in the blockchain will only have one contract.This contract will be registered with the public key of this person, i.e. the contract owner will be a public key that corresponds to a person.If I know this public key , can I retrieve the status of this contract?*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy solution is to manage contract address with a registry contract. When a contract is created it will call the registry contract and store the association with the sender.

```
contractRegistry.registerNew(msg.sender, address(this));
```

And `ContractRegistry` will have a `mapping (address => address) contracts`. That allows to determine the contract given its owner.

---

Another interesting alternative is to use the new opcode CREATE2 that allows the creation of contract with addresses generated deterministically.

Comment: Do you have a link with a better explanation of opcode CREATE2?

Comment: Check this post https://www.reddit.com/r/ethdev/comments/ahdf02/why_im_excited_for_create2/ it has more links.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to use the CREATE2 method like this: I'll generate the opcode of the contract and store it on a database. When I need to check the contract status I'll retrieve the opcode from the database and use it. Is it valid?